# Javascript custom date script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with a solution to have the following on a site: *The next day is 13 february 2014*

The date is to be displayed for two weeks and afterwards changed to the next date (27 february).

I have the following code for starting:

```
today = new Date();
compareDate = new Date(2014,0,30);
daysBetween = Math.floor((today-compareDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
if(daysBetween/14 == 1)
{
    document.write("13 february 2014");
}
else document.write(" ");
```

Also if the starting date changes, how can I apply changes to the script? Any help on completing the script is appreciated.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks, but I don't see how the script helps to plan future dates while the initial date is displayed.